# how to find duplicates in a given array and sum them in c

Tags: c, arrays

[How to add duplicated number in array please help me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiKtB.png)

```
int main()
{
    int i, j, tmp=0;
    int arr[10] = { 4, 7, 2, 4, 3, 1, 7, 9, 6, 5};
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        for(j = i + 1; j < 10; j++){

                if(arr[i] == arr[j]){
                    printf("arr[%d] = %d = arr[%d] = %d\n", i, arr[i], j, arr[j]);
                    tmp++;
                }
        }
    }
    printf("\nSUM is %d\n", tmp + tmp);
    return 0;
}
```

here is a code i can find only duplicate numbers but i can't find out duplicate sum of the numbers

Comment: Paste that code to question please

Comment: And state the specific problem.

Comment: #include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j, tmp=0;
    int arr[10] = { 4, 7, 2, 4, 3, 1, 7, 9, 6, 5};
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        for(j = i + 1; j < 10; j++){
            if(arr[i] == arr[j]){
                printf("arr[%d] = %d = arr[%d] = %d\n", i, arr[i], j, arr[j]);
                tmp++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\nSUM is %d\n", i+ tmp);
    
    return 0;
}

Comment: There is an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45846616/edit) button.

Comment: `tmp += arr[i];` in condition

Comment: Is the expected result `11`?

Comment: If the array values are bounded by some small number, it can be done much simpler and effective.

Comment: Do you want to *sum* the duplicates (add everything that's duplicate together), or *count* the duplicates (find out how many duplicates there are)?

Comment: Assuming you want the sum `4 + 7 = 11` as commented by @BLUEPIXY, initialise another flag array of the same length to zeros, to mark duplicate elements. Whenever you find a duplicate - if *neither* element was previously a duplicate, add the value to the sum and then set both the flag elements to 1.

Comment: . . . two advantages: if instead you keep a list or array of the duplicate values, you have to search the list every time you find a duplicate, and, the outer loop can `continue` if its value is already a dup.

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: It looks like there's a lot confusion with your question, because you didn't provide an expected output.

#### If you want to sum repeated numbers (as BLUEPIXY asked)...

You should add the value to `tmp` when you find the duplicate value instead of incrementing. Doing this would also alleviate the need to add `tmp` and `tmp` although I'm not sure what your intent was with that.

```
int main()
{
    int i, j, tmp=0;
    int arr[10] = { 4, 7, 2, 4, 3, 1, 7, 9, 6, 5};
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        for(j = i + 1; j < 10; j++){

                if(arr[i] == arr[j]){
                    printf("arr[%d] = %d = arr[%d] = %d\n", i, arr[i], j, arr[j]);
                    tmp += arr[i];
                }
        }
    }
    printf("\nSUM is %d\n", tmp);
    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
$ ./a.out
arr[0] = 4 = arr[3] = 4
arr[1] = 7 = arr[6] = 7

SUM is 11
```

#### If you just want to sum repeated numbers...

Simply sum them in the loop.

```
int main()
{
    int i, j, tmp=0;
    int arr[10] = { 4, 7, 2, 4, 3, 1, 7, 9, 6, 5};
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        for(j = i + 1; j < 10; j++){

                if(arr[i] == arr[j]){
                    printf("arr[%d] = %d = arr[%d] = %d\n", i, arr[i], j, arr[j]);
                    printf("SUM is %d\n\n", arr[i] + arr[i]);
                }
        }
    }
    //printf("\nSUM is %d\n", tmp + tmp);
    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
$ ./a.out
arr[0] = 4 = arr[3] = 4
arr[1] = 7 = arr[6] = 7

SUM is 11
```

Comment: The first code, does not satisfy BLUEPIXY sum of 11 if you change the last element `5` to `4`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Agreed. I'm waiting for more info/clarification from OP before investing more time in this question, though. :(

Answer (score 0):

you could create a temp array and add to it by traversing through your original array. for every number in the original array, then add it to the temp array. if the number is already in the temp array than that means there was already an occurrence of it and dont add it to the temp array. once you iterated over all elements in the original array, the temp array should only contain unique numbers. then just iterate through the newer array and sum them all up.